# Alinhar divs á esquerda com css, separando-as em grupos, sem quebra de linha

Tags: javascript, html, css

Estou procurando uma forma de alinhar `divs` á esquerda, porém, mante-las divididas em grupos, sem que um grupo quebre a linha. O código abaixo chega perto, mas gostaria de obter o resultado da imagem.

```css
.group {
    border-width: 1px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #008040;
    overflow: inherit;
    padding:5px;
    float:left;
    margin-left: 5px;
    margin-top:5px;
}

.machine {
    float: left;
    border-color: red;
    height: 75px;
    width: 50px;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-style: solid;
    box-sizing:border-box;    
}
```

```html
<div id="group1" class="group">
    <div id="subDiv1" class="machine">1</div>
    <div id="subDiv2" class="machine">2</div>
    <div id="subDiv3" class="machine">3</div>
    <div id="subDiv4" class="machine">4</div>
</div>

<div id="group2" class="group">
    <div id="subDiv1" class="machine">1</div>
    <div id="subDiv2" class="machine">2</div>
    <div id="subDiv3" class="machine">3</div>
    <div id="subDiv4" class="machine">4</div>
</div>

<div id="group3" class="group">
    <div id="subDiv1" class="machine">1</div>
    <div id="subDiv2" class="machine">2</div>
    <div id="subDiv3" class="machine">3</div>
    <div id="subDiv4" class="machine">4</div>
</div>
```

O código acima me dá este resultado (ATUAL):

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Mas eu gostaria de obter este outro resultado (DESEJADO):

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

É possível?

Comment: Complicado de fazer isso, eu particularmente não consigo imaginar um jeito simples de fazer ou algo pronto que faça, teria que identificar o "group" que excede a largura da tela e modificá-lo, por ai vai...Surgiram algumas ideia, mas nenhuma de simples implementação, caso eu encontre algo, posto aqui.

Comment: Este código chega muito próximo ao resultado esperado

[link]https://stackoverflow.com/a/44293889/1872936

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Acho que assim chega bem perto do que você procura. Mas fica bem difícil alinhar.

```css
.group {
  display: inline;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #008040;
  padding: 35px 5px;
  margin-left: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  line-height: 75px;
}

.machine {
  display: inline-block;
  border-color: red;
  height: 75px;
  width: 50px;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-style: solid;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div id="group1" class="group">
  <div id="subDiv1" class="machine">1</div>
  <div id="subDiv2" class="machine">2</div>
  <div id="subDiv3" class="machine">3</div>
  <div id="subDiv4" class="machine">4</div>
</div>

<div id="group2" class="group">
  <div id="subDiv1" class="machine">1</div>
  <div id="subDiv2" class="machine">2</div>
  <div id="subDiv3" class="machine">3</div>
  <div id="subDiv4" class="machine">4</div>
</div>

<div id="group3" class="group">
  <div id="subDiv1" class="machine">1</div>
  <div id="subDiv2" class="machine">2</div>
  <div id="subDiv3" class="machine">3</div>
  <div id="subDiv4" class="machine">4</div>
</div>
```

### EDIT

Se você não fizer questão dos espaços entre os grupos... Ele é o que efetivamente desalinha tudo:

```css
.group {
  display: inline;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #008040;
  padding: 35px 0px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  line-height: 75px;
}

.machine {
  display: inline-block;
  border-color: red;
  height: 75px;
  width: 50px;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-style: solid;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 3px 25px;
}
```

```html
<div id="group1" class="group">
  <div id="subDiv1" class="machine">1</div>
  <div id="subDiv2" class="machine">2</div>
  <div id="subDiv3" class="machine">3</div>
  <div id="subDiv4" class="machine">4</div>
</div>

<div id="group2" class="group">
  <div id="subDiv1" class="machine">1</div>
  <div id="subDiv2" class="machine">2</div>
  <div id="subDiv3" class="machine">3</div>
  <div id="subDiv4" class="machine">4</div>
</div>

<div id="group3" class="group">
  <div id="subDiv1" class="machine">1</div>
  <div id="subDiv2" class="machine">2</div>
  <div id="subDiv3" class="machine">3</div>
  <div id="subDiv4" class="machine">4</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Ficou excelente. Obrigado! Agora surgiu mais uma demanda: Preciso colocar um `header` no topo de cada grupo (acima das máquinas), por exemplo: Grupo 1, Grupo 2, etc...

Comment: Este seria o resultado final que preciso: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8VG3N.png

Comment: @pires E como você imagina isso dando certo quando se quebrasse no final da página?

Comment: Ainda não faço idéia, mas, talvez repedir o `header`.